# Splitting a unix file in shell script

Tags: unix

I have a file xyz1.sh with the content below with when i do cat xyz1 i get the result:

```
`$echo "Welcome to the server"
 Welcome to the server
 $echo "Hi this is content in the test file1."
 Hi this is content in the test file1.
 $ls
 abc.txt
 $date
 17 October 2016`
```

I aim to generate a new file xyz2 with only the shell commands. Is there any efficient way to achieve this apart from searching the xyz1 for some specific set of commands. Can there be any way to identify for all unix commands and get the lines out from the file?

xyz2 having content:

```
`$echo "Welcome to the server"
 $echo "Hi this is content in the test file1."
 $ls
 $date`
```

TIA

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Unix `sed` command to process the file. The following command 
**d**eletes every line that matches the given regular expression, `/^[^$]/` (which finds every line that does *not* being with a `$`). The output is then redirected to create the new file `xyz2`.

```
sed '/^[^$]/d' xyz1.sh > xyz2
```

Comment: Thanks. But its a sample code. And there might be files preceding hostname preceding each line

Comment: such as user@hostname :> cd dir1

Comment: so in this case, was looking for something which will identify this as a command

Comment: That would be a more complex question than the posted one. You should post that as a separate question, providing a [mcve] / sample file including all possible inputs.